# Read only new data dump from Azure Datakake Gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-data-lake, autoload

I have a requirement where I need to read only new data from the Datalake and run my Azure Databricks Spark Job.
I have to run my Spark job in batch mode thus don't want to use streaming. How do I ensure that every-time my Spark Job runs only new data dump is picked from container for spark job processing.

Comment: it's perfect case for structured streaming with trigger.once - why you can't use it? Otherwise you need to track somewhere which files were already processed & what aren't

Comment: @AlexOtt. Yes. I think AutoLoader would be the right choice for this as there is no much overhead of we handling the checkpoint. Autoloader does it for us.

Comment: You still need checkpoint directory, even with auto loader

Comment: Yes correct @AlexOtt